# Submitting and retrieving cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, server, backend

We are making an voting system for our website. You can post reports to the website which are saved as data files.
The current problem is that users can upvote or downvote as many times as they want because there is no barrier to stop the votes. What we want to happen is for users to be able to either upvote or downvote once.
We are trying to use cookies to achieve this (not the best system, I know, since people can just clear cookies, but this is a small student project and we just need the system down). We are able to set cookies in the upvote and downvote script. We have a `vote` cookie which is either set to `0`, `-1`, or `1`, depending on whether the user upvoted or not.
However, we are unable to retrieve the cookies accurately. When we try to retrieve the cookie `vote` using `$_COOKIE["vote"]` it doesn't give us a value.
Is there any reason why this cookie is not returning a value? Thank you in advance. All of our code is provided below if you need it.

```
    <?php
    $report = $_GET["report"];

    if(!isset($_COOKIE["vote"])) {
        setcookie("vote", "0", time() + 315360000, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $_COOKIE["vote"] = "0";
    }

    function upvote() {
        if(file_exists("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'])) {
            if($_COOKIE["vote"] == "1") { // Problem: $_COOKIE is not being compared to "1" properly, always returns false
                $filename = "DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'];
                $line = 3;
                $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] - 1);
                file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $lines));
                setcookie("vote", "0", time() + 315360000, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $_COOKIE["vote"] = "0";
            } else {
                $filename = "DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'];
                $line = 3;
                $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                if($_COOKIE["vote"] == "-1") {
                    $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] + 2);
                } else {
                    $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] + 1);
                }
                file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $lines));
                setcookie("vote", "1", time() + 315360000, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $_COOKIE["vote"] = "1";
            }
        }
    }

     function downvote() {
        if(file_exists("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'])) {
            if($_COOKIE["vote"] == "-1") {
                $filename = "DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'];
                $line = 3;
                $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] + 1);
                file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $lines));
                setcookie("vote", "0", time() + 315360000, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $_COOKIE["vote"] = "0";
            } else {
                $filename = "DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'];
                $line = 3;
                $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                if($_COOKIE["vote"] == "1") {
                    $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] - 2);
                } else {
                    $lines[$line] = (string)((int)$lines[$line] - 1);
                }
                file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $lines));
                setcookie("vote", "-1", time() + 315360000, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $_COOKIE["vote"] = "-1";
            }
        }
    }

    if($_POST["upvote_x"]) {
       upvote();
    }

    if($_POST["downvote_x"]) {
       downvote();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>View Report</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
                <li><a href="submissions.php">View</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;"> 
                <?php
                    if(file_exists("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'])) { // Check if the report exists
                        echo '<h2>Report Information:</h2>';
                        $data = file("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report']); // Gets array of lines in file

                        $upvote_button_url = $_COOKIE["vote"] == "1"?"Images/upvote.png":"Images/upvote_noclick.png";
                        $downvote_button_url = $_COOKIE["vote"] == "-1"?"Images/downvote.png":"Images/downvote_noclick.png";

                        echo '<h3 style="display:inline">Votes: </h3><p style="display:inline" class="wordwrap">'.$data[3].'</p>';
                        if($data[4] == "demo") {
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "This is a demonstrational report, and cannot be voted on.";
                            echo "<br>";
                        } else {
                            echo '<form method="post">';
                            echo    '<input type="image" src="'.$upvote_button_url.'" name="upvote" id="upvote" value="Upvote" onclick="changeUpvoteImage()" /><br/>';
                            echo    '<input type="image" src="'.$downvote_button_url.'" name="downvote" id="downvote" value="Downvote" onclick="changeDownvoteImage()" /><br/>';
                            echo '</form>';
                            echo '<p>If a report has or has less than -40 votes, it will be deleted.</p>';
                        }

                        if(file_exists('ImageUploads/'.pathinfo($GLOBALS['report'], PATHINFO_FILENAME))) {
                            echo '<li><img src="ImageUploads/'.$GLOBALS['report'].'" style="max-height: 600px; max-width: 700px"></li>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<img src="Images/missing.png" width="25%"><br>';
                        }
                        echo '<li><h3 style="display:inline">Location: </h3><p style="display:inline" class="wordwrap">'.htmlspecialchars($data[0]).'</p></li>';
                        echo '<li><h3 style="display:inline">Description: </h3><p style="display:inline" class="wordwrap">'.htmlspecialchars($data[1]).'</p></li>';
                        echo '<li><b><h3 style="display:inline">Urgency: </h3>';
                        if($data[2] < 30) {
                            echo "<span style='color: #1f7725'>Low</span>";
                        } else if($data[2] < 50) {
                            echo "<span style='color: #77711e'>Medium</span>";
                        } else if($data[2] < 80) {
                            echo "<span style='color: #774e1e'>High</span>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<span style='color: #771e1e'>Immediate</span>";
                        }
                        echo "</b></li>";

                        function delete() {
                            if(file_exists("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'])) {
                                unlink("DataUploads/".$GLOBALS['report']); //delete file
                            }
                            if(file_exists("ImageUploads/".$GLOBALS['report'])) {
                                unlink("ImageUploads/".$GLOBALS['report']); //delete file
                            }
                        }

                        if($data[3] <= -40 && $data[4] != "demo") {
                            delete();
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<h1>No report found with the name "'.$GLOBALS['report'].'". Check the URL!</h1>';
                        echo '<img src="Images/missing-report.jpg" width="50%">';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <script> 
            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }

            function getCookieValue(a) {
                var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
                return b ? b.pop() : '';
            }

            function changeUpvoteImage() {
                var img = document.getElementById("upvote");
                img.src = "Images/upvote.png";
                return false;
            }

            function changeDownvoteImage() {
                var img = document.getElementById("downvote");
                img.src = "Images/downvote.png";
                return false;
            }

            if(getCookieValue(getUrlVars("report") + "vote") == 1) {
                changeUpvoteImage();
            } else if(getCookieValue(getUrlVars("report") + "vote") == -1) {
                changeDownvoteImage();
            }
        </script>
        <script>
            if(window.history.replaceState) {
                window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `session` instead of `cookie` . some browsers will take long to update or delete a `cookie` but a session will update instantly if changed.

Comment: I would use sessions, but I want the vote to last permanently rather than when the user closes their browser.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to set the cookies:

```
setcookie("vote", "some_value", time() + (315360000 * 30), "/");
```

(This worked for me)